# R: Add the concatenated output of a cat with line breaks (type: NULL) to a cell in a dataframe

Tags: r, paste, cat

I am trying to add the output of a cat with line breaks to a cell in a dataframe I created.

For example:

`dataset[2,3] <- cat('I want this output','\n','in that cell')`

It returns the error
`Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero`

Which is caused by the fact that the output of `cat` is not character (string), it is `NULL`.

`paste` seemed like a good option but I cannot do line breaks with paste. I also used `paste` wrapped around a `cat` but it did not work.

`writeLines` also returns a `NULL`, so that seems like a no-go.

This is something Excel alone can do with `CHAR(10)`.

How to add line breaks while maintaining the output?

I surpassed this with paste and `&CHAR(10)&` in R, but is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to create a column, use `paste` instead of `cat` as `cat` only prints and not return value

```
dataset[2,3] <- paste0('I want this output','\n','in that cell')
```

Also, assuming that the third column is `character` class and not `factor`